# How to convert this complex json with string inside to normal json object like out put

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

HI my input json is like this and i want convert this to expected output using lodash  _.map function
    [

```
    {
    "img":"imageurl",
    "qualityJsonString": "{\"MorphoScore\":\"204\",\"AwareScore\":\"0\",\"QualityCategory\":\"Medium\",\"QualityAttributes\":{\"ISO\":{\"Tinted Glasses\":true,\"Horizontally Centered Face\":true,\"Hotspots\":true,\"Vertical Face Position\":false,\"Exposure\":false,\"Length of Head\":false,\"Sharpness\":true,\"Compliant\":false,\"Width of Head\":true,\"Uniform Lighting\":true,\"Greyscale  Profile\":true,\"Natural Skin Colour\":true,\"Frontal Pose\":true,\"Resolution\":false},\"Aware\":[{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_FACIAL_BRIGHTNESS\",\"qualityScore\":94.140625},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SMILE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":7.766985283983502},{\"qualityParameter\":\"RIGHT_EYE_CLOSED_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DARK_GLASSES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FACIAL_DYNAMIC_RANGE\",\"qualityScore\":7.912889336229961},{\"qualityParameter\":\"OFF_ANGLE_GAZE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":19.230365753173473},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_BACKGROUND_UNIFORMITY\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DEGREE_OF_ILLUMINATION_ASYMMETRY\",\"qualityScore\":67.58262728281615},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEIGHT_TO_WIDTH_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":1.2487562189054726},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DEGREE_OF_CLUTTER\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FACE_COUNT\"},{\"qualityParameter\":\"POSE_ANGLE_YAW\",\"qualityScore\":-1.655534847997771},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HAIR_COVERED_RIGHT_EYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"LEFT_EYE_CLOSED_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_FACIAL_SATURATION\",\"qualityScore\":1.3333333333333286},{\"qualityParameter\":\"REDEYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEAD_HEIGHT_TO_IMAGE_HEIGHT_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.9083665338645418},{\"qualityParameter\":\"MASK_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":66.04184751157408},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_SEPARATION\",\"qualityScore\":71.55286507191728},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SHARPNESS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":75.54344930211819},{\"qualityParameter\":\"JPEG_QUALITY_LEVEL\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FOCUS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":82.07793032254156},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_AXIS_ANGLE\",\"qualityScore\":2.2025981617658053},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BACKGROUND_PAD_TYPE\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"CENTERLINE_LOCATION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.48880597014925375},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_ROI_FOREGROUND_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"LEFT_EYE_VALID_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":76.16672180697158},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HAIR_COVERED_LEFT_EYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FOREHEAD_COVERING_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"GLASSES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":2.7458807359307684},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEAVY_FRAMES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"GLARE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"IMAGE_WIDTH_TO_HEAD_WIDTH_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":1.4055944055944056},{\"qualityParameter\":\"POSE_ANGLE_PITCH\",\"qualityScore\":-1.1384115595433095},{\"qualityParameter\":\"RIGHT_EYE_VALID_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":75.0017445765546},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BRIGHTNESS_SCORE\",\"qualityScore\":100.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_ROI_BACKGROUND_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BACKGROUND_TYPE\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"UNNATURAL_COLOR_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":8.087372947615322},{\"qualityParameter\":\"NUMBER_CHANNELS\",\"qualityScore\":3.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SHADOWS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":7.169740789649495},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_CONTRAST\",\"qualityScore\":87.5},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_BACKGROUND_GRAY\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_AXIS_LOCATION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.6180278884462151},{\"qualityParameter\":\"IMAGE_FORMAT\",\"qualityScore\":4.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242}],\"ISOBestPractice\":{\"Mouth Closed Best Practice\":true,\"Eyes not Red  Best Practice\":true,\"Eyes Gaze Best Practice\":true,\"Resolution Best Practice\":false,\"Uniform Background Best Practice\":false,\"Frontal Pose Best Practice\":true,\"Width of Head Best Practice\":true,\"Length of Head Best Practice\":false,\"Eyes Open Best Practice\":true,\"Compliant Best Practice\":false,\"Image Width to Height Best Practice\":true},\"ICAO\":{\"No Dark Lenses and no heavy frames and no glares\":true,\"Natural skin tones\":true,\"Facing square on to the camera\":true,\"Face coverage upto 70ָ0% of the photograph\":false,\"Colour neutral\":true,\"No image more than 6-months old\":true,\"Uniform lighting and no shadows\":true,\"Compliant\":false,\"Plain light-coloured background\":false,\"Eye Separation\":false,\"Forehead coverage and Mask Detection\":true,\"One face in image and no smile\":true,\"Sharp and Focus\":true,\"Brightness and Contrast\":false,\"Looking directly at the camera\":true,\"Eyes open and clearly visible\":true},\"DepartmentStandard\":{\"Has Natural Skin Colour\":true,\"Mouth Closed\":true,\"Good Vertical Face Position\":false,\"Horizontally Centered Face\":true,\"Eyes not Red\":true,\"Length of Head\":false,\"Compliant\":false,\"Eyes Open\":true,\"Width of Head\":true,\"No Tinted Glasses\":false,\"Good Exposure\":false,\"Good Greyscale\":true,\"No Hotspots\":true,\"Frontal Pose\":true,\"One Face\":true,\"Resolution\":false}}}"
    },{

        "img":"imageurl",
    "qualityJsonString": "{\"MorphoScore\":\"204\"}
    }]
```

Above json have field called "qualityJsonString" this object is a string json so am facing issue to convert this string to proper json format

and i need out put json like this below format

```
{"img":"image url",
  "QualityAttributes": {
    "ISO":{
     "Tinted Glasses":true,
      ......
     },
     "ISOBestPractice":{
        "Mouth Closed Best Practice":true,
         ......
     },
     "ICAO":{
        "No Dark Lenses and no heavy frames and no glares":true,
         ......
     },
     "DepartmentStandard":{
        "Has Natural Skin Colour":true,
        .....
     }

  } 


},
{"img":"image url",
  "QualityAttributes": {
    "ISO":{
     "Tinted Glasses":true,
      ......
     },
     "ISOBestPractice":{
        "Mouth Closed Best Practice":true,
         ......
     },
     "ICAO":{
        "No Dark Lenses and no heavy frames and no glares":true,
         ......
     },
     "DepartmentStandard":{
        "Has Natural Skin Colour":true,
        .....
     }

  } 


}
```

Please help me to make it like this, i tried field.toJSON but its not converting full jSON

Comment: can we have a full json and as well what you have done so far?

Comment: That JSON doesn't parse. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: its working till qualityString key and its real json, only thing is string inside json

Comment: If the string is improperly formatted/escaped inside the JSON the JSON won't parse. You need to fix the formatting before you can do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have parsed your input JSON at here [Parsed Json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2308b6e1557a45c59eeb56321c87b8c1) by removing errors.

The following lodash code will give you the desired output.

```
_.map(myInputArray, (element) => (
    {
       img: element.img, 
       QualityAttributes: element.qualityJsonString.QualityAttributes
    }));
```

Comment: how do i print the result?

Comment: {img: image url,QualityAttributes: undefined} .  this came

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it.

```
var json = {
    "img":"imageurl",
    "qualityJsonString": "{\"MorphoScore\":\"204\",\"AwareScore\":\"0\",\"QualityCategory\":\"Medium\",\"QualityAttributes\":{\"ISO\":{\"Tinted Glasses\":true,\"Horizontally Centered Face\":true,\"Hotspots\":true,\"Vertical Face Position\":false,\"Exposure\":false,\"Length of Head\":false,\"Sharpness\":true,\"Compliant\":false,\"Width of Head\":true,\"Uniform Lighting\":true,\"Greyscale  Profile\":true,\"Natural Skin Colour\":true,\"Frontal Pose\":true,\"Resolution\":false},\"Aware\":[{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_FACIAL_BRIGHTNESS\",\"qualityScore\":94.140625},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SMILE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":7.766985283983502},{\"qualityParameter\":\"RIGHT_EYE_CLOSED_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DARK_GLASSES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FACIAL_DYNAMIC_RANGE\",\"qualityScore\":7.912889336229961},{\"qualityParameter\":\"OFF_ANGLE_GAZE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":19.230365753173473},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_BACKGROUND_UNIFORMITY\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DEGREE_OF_ILLUMINATION_ASYMMETRY\",\"qualityScore\":67.58262728281615},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEIGHT_TO_WIDTH_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":1.2487562189054726},{\"qualityParameter\":\"DEGREE_OF_CLUTTER\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FACE_COUNT\"},{\"qualityParameter\":\"POSE_ANGLE_YAW\",\"qualityScore\":-1.655534847997771},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HAIR_COVERED_RIGHT_EYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"LEFT_EYE_CLOSED_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_FACIAL_SATURATION\",\"qualityScore\":1.3333333333333286},{\"qualityParameter\":\"REDEYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEAD_HEIGHT_TO_IMAGE_HEIGHT_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.9083665338645418},{\"qualityParameter\":\"MASK_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":66.04184751157408},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_SEPARATION\",\"qualityScore\":71.55286507191728},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SHARPNESS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":75.54344930211819},{\"qualityParameter\":\"JPEG_QUALITY_LEVEL\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FOCUS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":82.07793032254156},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_AXIS_ANGLE\",\"qualityScore\":2.2025981617658053},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BACKGROUND_PAD_TYPE\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"CENTERLINE_LOCATION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.48880597014925375},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_ROI_FOREGROUND_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"LEFT_EYE_VALID_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":76.16672180697158},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HAIR_COVERED_LEFT_EYE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"FOREHEAD_COVERING_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"GLASSES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":2.7458807359307684},{\"qualityParameter\":\"HEAVY_FRAMES_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"GLARE_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":0.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"IMAGE_WIDTH_TO_HEAD_WIDTH_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":1.4055944055944056},{\"qualityParameter\":\"POSE_ANGLE_PITCH\",\"qualityScore\":-1.1384115595433095},{\"qualityParameter\":\"RIGHT_EYE_VALID_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":75.0017445765546},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BRIGHTNESS_SCORE\",\"qualityScore\":100.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_ROI_BACKGROUND_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"BACKGROUND_TYPE\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"UNNATURAL_COLOR_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":8.087372947615322},{\"qualityParameter\":\"NUMBER_CHANNELS\",\"qualityScore\":3.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"SHADOWS_LIKELIHOOD\",\"qualityScore\":7.169740789649495},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_CONTRAST\",\"qualityScore\":87.5},{\"qualityParameter\":\"PERCENT_BACKGROUND_GRAY\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242},{\"qualityParameter\":\"EYE_AXIS_LOCATION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":0.6180278884462151},{\"qualityParameter\":\"IMAGE_FORMAT\",\"qualityScore\":4.0},{\"qualityParameter\":\"J2K_COMPRESSION_RATIO\",\"qualityScore\":3.373901808553242}],\"ISOBestPractice\":{\"Mouth Closed Best Practice\":true,\"Eyes not Red  Best Practice\":true,\"Eyes Gaze Best Practice\":true,\"Resolution Best Practice\":false,\"Uniform Background Best Practice\":false,\"Frontal Pose Best Practice\":true,\"Width of Head Best Practice\":true,\"Length of Head Best Practice\":false,\"Eyes Open Best Practice\":true,\"Compliant Best Practice\":false,\"Image Width to Height Best Practice\":true},\"ICAO\":{\"No Dark Lenses and no heavy frames and no glares\":true,\"Natural skin tones\":true,\"Facing square on to the camera\":true,\"Face coverage upto 70ָ0% of the photograph\":false,\"Colour neutral\":true,\"No image more than 6-months old\":true,\"Uniform lighting and no shadows\":true,\"Compliant\":false,\"Plain light-coloured background\":false,\"Eye Separation\":false,\"Forehead coverage and Mask Detection\":true,\"One face in image and no smile\":true,\"Sharp and Focus\":true,\"Brightness and Contrast\":false,\"Looking directly at the camera\":true,\"Eyes open and clearly visible\":true},\"DepartmentStandard\":{\"Has Natural Skin Colour\":true,\"Mouth Closed\":true,\"Good Vertical Face Position\":false,\"Horizontally Centered Face\":true,\"Eyes not Red\":true,\"Length of Head\":false,\"Compliant\":false,\"Eyes Open\":true,\"Width of Head\":true,\"No Tinted Glasses\":false,\"Good Exposure\":false,\"Good Greyscale\":true,\"No Hotspots\":true,\"Frontal Pose\":true,\"One Face\":true,\"Resolution\":false}}}"
    };

var parsedQualityJSON = $.parseJSON(json.qualityJsonString);
console.log(parsedQualityJSON);
```

In that example the `parsedQualityJSON` variable holds the new json object.

I did remove the second section of your Json string due to it being incorrectly formatted but due to the missing data compared to the first one I'm thinking thats because of how you copied it across, if that isn't the case like mentioned in the comments you need to check the Json strings your using.

Comment: there is one more object called  QualityAttributes inside qualityJsonString.  will i get all in same normal json format?

Comment: Yes once its parsed it will be available, use the developer console to view the object once parsed. (F12 on most browsers)

Comment: that will be the `]` following the second Json string. like mentioned in the comments and the later part of my answer you need to check them.